# mediarecorder performance problem

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I have MediaRecorder to stream media content over tcp connection:
MediaRecorder m_mediaRecorder;
Socket m_socket;
....

ParcelFileDescriptor m_pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(m_socket);
m_mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(m_pfd.getFileDescriptor());
... 
I have error and "info" handlers implemented in my class
m_mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(this);
m_mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);

I am required to close media streaming session if bandwidth of tcp link is insufficient to support "live" streaming. Is there any method to "catch" bandwidth issue in Java code?
I can see warnings in LogCat: "OsclNativeFile: writing xx bytes takes too long", but nothing is ever caught in my error/ info handlers.
Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using TCP, you can always check if you're able to send the same FPS/bitrate as the cameras is suppose to give you.